# How to call function pointer for class member function

Tags: c++

I tried to implement a function pointer calling to the class member. I have implemented the sample and assigned the function pointer successfully. But if I try to call the function pointer it is throwing an error. Kindly refer below sample code of what I implemented and assist me on this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myfunpoin
{
  public:

    int addd(int a,int b)
   {
      return a + b;
   }

    int sub(int a, int b)
    {
      return a - b;
    }

};

int main()
{
    myfunpoin a;
    int (myfunpoin::*myval)(int, int);
    myval =&myfunpoin::addd;
    myval(1, 2);//i want to invoke this function pointer but getting error
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need an instance to call a member function

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show the error you get.

Comment: It's not a syntax you would guess (although you could try looking it up in a book) `(a.*myval)(1, 2);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> myval(1, 2);
> ```

This cannot work because you haven't passed the implicit instance argument.

A pointer to member function is called like a member function, except in place of the function name, you have indirection operator and the pointer to member function. Example:

```
(a.*myval)(1, 2);
```

The parenthesis are needed because function call operator has higher precedence and the expression would have a wrong meaning otherwise.

Comment: @idclev463035818 In my opinion the instance *is* passed as an argument. It just has special syntax compared to the other arguments. I added "implicit".

Comment: ok, nevermind then. Adding "implicit" already helped me ;)